# Comparing '1' and '_' in PowerShell gives unexpected result

Tags: powershell, comparison-operators

On comparing '1' with '_' the answer I'm expecting is '1' < '_' because their Ascii values are 49 and 95 respectively. But the answer is the other way. For that matter, even ':' instead of '_' gives the same result.

```
[byte][char]'1' -gt [byte][char]'_'
>> False
```

which makes sense. However:

```
'1' -gt '_'
>> True
```

Would appreciate any pointers on what I may be missing here. In essence I'm looking for a reliable way to lexicographically compare strings in powershell. Thanks!

Comment: This should answer your question: `'1'.CompareTo('_')` vs `([char]'1').CompareTo([char]'_')`

Answer (score 3):

Your first example is using [`Byte.CompareTo(Byte)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte.compareto?view=net-7.0#system-byte-compareto(system-byte)) whereas your second example is using [`String.CompareTo(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto?view=net-7.0#system-string-compareto(system-string)).

`'1' -gt '_'` returns `$true` because `1` *follows* `_`.

Two different ways you could see it:

```bash
'1'.CompareTo('_')                  # => 1
([char] '1').CompareTo([char] '_')  # => -46

'1', '_' | Sort-Object              # => `_` goes first
'1', '_' -as [char[]] | Sort-Object # => `1` goes first
```

Comment: I suppose what I don't completely understand is why, or in which manner, does 1 follow _

Comment: @UtkarshKajaria you would get your answer if you click the `String.CompareTo(String)` link and read the .NET documentation

Comment: @UtkarshKajaria strings and chars use different comparer it's as simple as that. The comparer interface is implemented differently for strings and chars

Comment: I reread it. So it does say "You cannot use this method to perform culture-insensitive or ordinal comparisons." Although not sure why would -gt not use ordinal comparisons by default in PS. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: I guess that's a bit extreme, but at least it could provide an option for it. Thanks though!

Comment: @UtkarshKajaria well the thing is, PowerShell is a case-insensitive language, all PowerShell [comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2) are insensitive by default and their sensitive counterpart can be used by adding `c` to the operator, i.e.: `-ge` (insensitive) and `-cge` sensitive. In that sense, `'a' -ge 'A'` is `true` where as `'a' -cge 'A'` is `false`. What happens behind the scenes is the engine using a different Comparer.

Comment: Behind the scenes the engine would be using something like `'a'.CompareTo('A')` for case sensitive and for case insensitive it could be using something like `[System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare('a', 'A')` (unsure about this, the only way to have a 100% correct answer is to look into the source code. Hope that sheds that light into it @UtkarshKajaria

Answer (score 3):

Let's break down your two examples.

```
[byte][char]'1' -gt [byte][char]'_'
```

In this example you're comparing a `byte` to a `byte`. It is important to note that [`byte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte?view=net-7.0) and [`char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=net-7.0) are both numeric values. The only real difference is that a `char` is 16 bits (so it can represent Unicode characters) and a `byte` is only 8 bits. Casting a `string` to a `char` gets the numeric representation of the character in the string (provided the string only contains a single character).

This means that `[byte][char]'1'` results in the number `49` and `[byte][char]'_'` results in `95`. The expression will evaluate to `false` since 49 is not greater than 95.

Now let's look at your second example

```
'1' -gt '_'
```

In this example, you're comparing a `string` to a `string`. When comparing two strings using `-gt`, `-ge`, `-lt`, or `-le`, it uses the [alphabetical sort order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order) to determine whether or not the expression should be `true` or `false`, not the numeric values of the characters in the string. If one string is sorted before another, the first string is considered less than the second and vice versa.

You can see this behavior if you pass some strings to the `Sort-Object` cmdlet.

```
'1', '2', '3', '_' | Sort-Object
# returns '_', '1', '2', '3'
```

This means that your second example will return `true` because in the sort order implemented by .NET, `_` comes before `1`.

The order of special characters can vary by language and/or culture as there does not appear to be a standard, however it is pretty universally accepted that special characters should be sorted before numbers and letters.